# MVC Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when accessing model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Just getting into MVC, and having a bit of a problem.  My view is throwing the above error when trying to display a string from a newly created model.  The error is on @Model.UserName

View:

```
@using Nam.Models
@model Nam.Models.UserInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Operations";
}

<h2>Operations</h2>
<table border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="30%" align="left">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><b>User Info</b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>User:</b></td>
        <td>@Model.UserName</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="40%" align="right">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><b>Main Info</b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserInfo UID = new UserInfo();
        {
            UID.UserName = "Name";
            UID.UserID = 0;
        }

        return View(UID);
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace Nam.Models
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Nam" />
    <add namespace="DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="Nam.Models"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: What page are you calling ? Looks like your view is for `Operations` Where is the action method for that ?

Comment: View is Operations.cshtml

Comment: I see what you mean. Changed ActionResult to Operations and still got the error

Comment: Can you post your Operations action method ?

Comment: Ok, I copied the ActionResult from my OperationsController to the HomeController, and it worked.  So how do I switch which controller my View uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model which is pass through index action method is not reached to your view.
The problem could be your corresponding view that is not rendered through your `Index()`method.

Try to add your view name in Index method return type.

```
return View("Operations",UID);
```

Or try to create view name with the exact name of Action Method.(Eg: Index.cshtml) and paste your present view code in Index.cshtml.

Comment: Not that, but your comment did trigger a light bulb.  I've figured it out.  Thanks for letting me waste some of your time, sorry :P

Comment: No problem always waste my time like this :D